# unset PHP session if page refresh

Tags: php, session

I have a registration page that uses PHP validation. The PHP comes in a separate file. I used session to pass the error messages from the php validation handler to the registration page. I used unset(session) for other pages so when the user navigates from other page, the error msgs will be unset. What if the user tries to refresh the page by clicking the link of registration again from the navigation bar? I cannot unset the error messages from the start of registration page because it will unset the session variables before the error messages displays.

Answer (score 1):

your whole approach is wrong.

just make it one PHP page and one html template.

then do whatever you want. that's the way PHP works

Comment: You mean by handling data to itself? I was told that using a separate file for data handler is a good approach especially if I want to avoid double submission because of refresh.

Comment: one who told you that have no clue. you have to do a redirect in order to avoid double submit

Comment: yes. That is why I used header(location:registration.php), to redirect back to the main page with the error messages stored in session variables.

Comment: use my answer then. abandon that silly setup you have and make it right way.